# Typescript: can't call function from another module

Tags: javascript, typescript

My current project is a simple multiplayer game. Both client and server are written in Typescript. The client only processes the input and renders the game, all logic is implemented on the serverside.

The server code is executed with nodejs and structured like this

- main.ts contains an express server and serves the html file with the client-side script. Moreover it sets up socket.io, creates a new instance of Game and creates a new instance of `Player` for each socket that connects.
- game.ts exports the classes `Game` and `Player`. The `Game` is actually only a container for all important data. It stores a list of all players and a list of all gameObjects. `Game` implements the method `requestSpawn(...)` which checks if a new gameObject may be spawned. The class `Player` is just a wrapper for a socket.io socket. It processes incoming and outgoing messages. If the client tries to spawn a GameObject a message is sent to the server and arrives at the socket stored in the `Player` instance. The `Player` instance then calls `requestSpawn` to try to spawn the desired `GameObject`.
- GameObjects.ts exports the interface `GameObject` and various implementations of this interface.

The game runs like this:

1. A person clicks inside the html-canvas
2. A new "REQUESTSPAWN" message is packaged and sent to the server
3. A `Player` instance receives the message and calls `requestSpawn` on its instance of `Game`
4. The `Game` instance creates a new `GameObject` of the correct type at the correct position and adds it to the list of `GameObjects`
5. This new `GameObject` should now be updated.

Which it isn't.
Here's the relevant code:

game.ts

```
import go = module("GameObjects"); 
import util = module("Utilities");

//...

export class Game {
    private players: Player[];
    public gameObjects:go.GameObject[];
    private gameObjectCounter: number;

    constructor() {
        this.players = [];
        this.gameObjectCounter = 0;
        this.gameObjects = [];
        var prev = Date.now();
        var deltaTime = Date.now() - prev;
        setInterval(() =>{ deltaTime = Date.now() - prev; prev = Date.now(); this.update(deltaTime); }, 200);
    }

    broadcast(msg: Message) {
        this.players.forEach((player) => { player.send(msg); });
    }

    requestSpawn(msg:RequestSpawnMessage, clientID:number): bool {
        var pos = new util.Vector2(msg.x, msg.y);        
        var o: go.GameObject;
        switch (msg.tag) {
            case UID.FACTORY:                                        
                o = new go.Factory(pos.clone(), this.players[clientID], this.newGameObject());
            case UID.ROBOT:
                o = new go.Robot(pos.clone(), this.players[clientID], this.newGameObject());
        }
        this.broadcast(new SpawnMessage(msg.tag, o.id, clientID, pos.x, pos.y));
        this.gameObjects.push(o);
        console.log(this.gameObjects);
        o.update(1);
        console.log("tried to update the factory");
        return true;
    }

    update(deltaTime){
        this.gameObjects.forEach((object) =>{object.update(deltaTime); });
    }

    addPlayer(socket: Socket) {        
        var player = new Player(this, socket, this.players.length);
        this.players.push(player);
    }
    newGameObject() : number {
        return this.gameObjectCounter++;
    }
}
```

GameObjects.ts

```
export import util = module("Utilities");
export import s = module("server");
export import g = module("game");

export interface GameObject{
    tag: g.UID;
    id:number;
    player: g.Player;
    clientId: number;
    pos:util.Vector2;
    getPos():util.Vector2;
    setPos(newPos:util.Vector2);
    // !TODO how to make that const?
    boundingBox: util.Rectangle;
    update(deltaTime:number);
}

export class Factory implements GameObject {
    tag: g.UID;
    id: number;
    player: g.Player;
    clientId: number;
    server: s.Server;
    //variables for handling the delay between spawning robots
    private current_time: number;
    public delay: number;
    boundingBox: util.Rectangle;

    public static dimensions = new util.Vector2(30, 30);
    constructor(pos: util.Vector2, player:g.Player, id: number) {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.tag = g.UID.FACTORY;
        this.player = player;
        this.clientId = this.player.getID();
        this.current_time = 0;
        this.delay = 1;
        this.id = id;
        this.boundingBox = new util.Rectangle(pos, Factory.dimensions.x, Factory.dimensions.y);
        console.log("just created a factory");
        //this.update(1);
    }

    pos: util.Vector2;
    getPos() { return this.pos; }
    setPos(pos: util.Vector2) { this.pos = pos; }

    public once = true;
    //check if it's time to create a new robot
    public update(deltaTime: number) {
        console.log("updating a factory");

        //this code will produce a robot just once, this is handy for development, since there's not so much waiting time
        if (this.once) { this.player.requestSpawn(g.UID.ROBOT, this.pos.x, this.pos.y); console.log("just spawned a robot"); }
        this.once = false;
        /*this.current_time += deltaTime/1000;
        if (this.current_time > this.delay*(Factory.count+1)/(Mine.count+1)) {
            this.current_time = 0;
            this.spawnRobot();
        }*/
    }
}


//this will be the fighting robot meant to destroy enemy factories
export class Robot implements GameObject{
    tag: g.UID;
    id: number;
    player:g.Player;
    clientId: number;
    game: g.Game;
    boundingBox: util.Rectangle;
    // ! TODO constants should have capital letters.
    public static radius = 15;
    constructor(pos:util.Vector2,player:g.Player,id:number){ 
        this.tag = g.UID.ROBOT;
        this.player=player;
        this.clientId = this.player.getID();
        this.boundingBox = new util.Rectangle(pos, Robot.radius, Robot.radius);
    }

    pos:util.Vector2;
    getPos(){return this.pos;}
    setPos(pos:util.Vector2){this.pos=pos;}

    //now the robot is moved by keyboard input but soon it will check the gameObjects array and search for the closest enemy,
    //in order to attack it
    public update(deltaTime: number) {

    }
}
```

Right now the first call of the update method of a factory instance spawns a robot, after that the factory "sleeps". Robots do nothing in their update method.

I would like to lead your eyes on two lines of the code:
 - In the `requestSpawn` method the `GameObject` is updated immediately with deltaTime=1

That means that directly after spawning a factory, a robot should be spawned, too. But that doesn't happen. I added a `console.log` call inside the `requestSpawn` method. It successfully prints "just tried to update a factory" but nevertheless, nothing happens.
So I supposed that the update method was not working properly and added a `console.log` call there, too. It's the first line of the `Factory's` `update` method and should print "updating a factory". But that never happens.

I was really confused. The method should be called but it isn't. Although it is declared public, I thought that the problem might have something to do with access rights. So this here's the second line of code, that I would like to point out:
 - in the constructor of the Factory, I've commented out a call to `this.update(1)`.

I figured that at least the very own constructor should be able to call the update method. Indeed, it is. When this line is not commented out, update is called once. The factory then tries to spawn a new robot and calls `requestSpawn()` on its instance of `Game`. As a consequence a new robot is created and a `SpawnMessage` goes out to all clients. The robot even appears in the client's browser tab.

Therefore it's obvious that the method is not called. Everything works fine, the message parsing, factory updating and robot creating are correct. The only problem is that all calls to update from within `Game` are not executed. What went wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've posted a lot of code, and there may be other issues, but at least one is that you are missing the `break` in your switch statement...

```
switch (msg.tag) {
        case UID.FACTORY:                                        
            o = new go.Factory(pos.clone(), this.players[clientID], this.newGameObject());
        case UID.ROBOT:
            o = new go.Robot(pos.clone(), this.players[clientID], this.newGameObject());
}
```

...and therefore always creating a `Robot`, which traces nothing in its `update()` method. (If you try to create a `Factory`, you succeed, but then immediately overwrite it by assigning a new `Robot` to the same var `o`).

Consider this simplified example:

```
interface GameObject {
    update():void;
}

class Factory implements GameObject {
    update():void {
        console.log("Factory");
    }
}

class Robot implements GameObject {
    update():void {
        console.log("Robot");
    }
}

class Test {

    private o:GameObject;

    constructor(index:number){
        switch(index){
            case 1:
                this.o = new Factory();
            case 2:
                this.o = new Robot();
        }
        this.o.update();
    }
}

class BreakTest {

    private o:GameObject;

    constructor(index:number){
        switch(index){
            case 1:
                this.o = new Factory();
                break;
            case 2:
                this.o = new Robot();
                break; // Not necessary in final case, but good form IMO.
        }
        this.o.update();
    }
}

var t = new Test(1);       // Traces 'Robot'
var tt = new Test(2);      // Traces 'Robot'

var b = new BreakTest(1);  // Traces 'Factory'
var bt = new BreakTest(2); // Traces 'Robot'
```

([Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch))

Comment: yes, that works. What an embarrasing mistake. Thank you for finding it